# verilog signal value annotaion

Tags: annotations, verilog, hierarchy

Anyone:

I'm trying to use gtkwave-3-3.62 signal value annotation function to hierarchical RTL structure with RTLbrowse.

The vermin parser response has no error.
The vcd signal values are shown in the waveform window seemed correctly.
And the values are also shown in the RTLbrowse window when it's the top module.
However, signal values are not annotated to the lower level modules.

How do I annotate these signal values to the lower level modules?

I'm very happy if anyone could help me.
And thanks.

Bets Regards,
Yoshihide Sugiura

Comment: Are the lower level modules in a library (usually prefixed with `-v` or `-y` option), or inside a ``  `celldefine  `` macro? I haven't used gtkwave; other verilog waveform viewers I worked with do stop annotating cells under these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is an issue regarding something like generate statements or escaped identifiers in hierarchy names.  It's hard to say.

One thing you could do is look at the hierarchy in gtkwave versus what you see in rtlbrowse.  Are there any differences?  If they don't match up, annotation won't occur for a level in the source as rtlbrowse has no idea how to correlate its hierarchy with that of the dump file.

Something I should do is take the "Open Source Instantiation" mechanism used in FST (newer versions of Icarus support this) and apply that to signal annotation.  Then it would not need vermin at all.

Also...I'd suggest using FST as the dumpfile format if you aren't already.

-Tony